# $_SESSION Variables appear to not transfer

Tags: php, session

So I have a site the displays one menu if the client is not logged in, and then another if they are logged in. As I updated my server to the latest version of PHP my old way of doing this no longer works with session_register. So I am trying to get the data into a $_SESSION and I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Any help would be appreciated.

Login Script to set $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $my_username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $my_password;
```

From what I know that should set `$_SESSION['username']` as the username IE: **tomm21**

The next page then asks if the user is registered by checking if the

```
$_SESSION['username'] == 'tomm21';
```

It gets the username from another script to verify that the information is only displayed to this user.

This is the code that is causing an issue.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['username'] == "tomm21") {
    include("includes/menu2.php");
} else {
    include("includes/menu.php");
}
?>
```

When I log in it takes me to the correct page proving the details are right however the wrong menu is displayed.

The login does shot back errors if the username and passwords are wrong so I know for a fact that part is working. I just do not think it is registering the Session correctly or being called back correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use `session_start();` before assigning values to **$_SESSION** ?

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` on every page?

Comment: yes I am sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Leonardo, you did make me think to check my login script and I was not calling session_start(); their. Thank you so much!

Comment: Post an official answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're starting session by `session_start();` at the begining of both files and you are **not** calling `session_destroy();`.